# How to test whether a word is in singular form or not in python?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to get whether a word is in singular form or in plural form by using nltk pos_tag. But the results are not accurate.

So, I need a way to find how can get whether a word is in singular form or in plural form? moreover I need it without using any python package.

Comment: you need some sort of morphological analyzer. possibly it's hard to get out of nltk but you can try with WordNetLemmatizer.

Answer (score 14):

For English, every word should somehow have a root lemma where the default plurality is singular.

Assuming that you have only nouns in your list, you can try this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

def isplural(word):
    lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, 'n')
    plural = True if word is not lemma else False
    return plural, lemma

nounls = ['geese', 'mice', 'bars', 'foos', 'foo', 
                'families', 'family', 'dog', 'dogs']

for nn in nounls:
    isp, lemma = isplural(nn)
    print nn, lemma, isp
```

You will have **a problem when word is out of wordnet**, then you have to use more sophiscated [classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) or [finite state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) out of `NLTK`.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want an English solution, you can do something similar to 2er0's solution a bit more directly with [pattern-en](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en):

```
from pattern.en import singularize

def isplural(pluralForm):
     singularForm = singularize(pluralForm)
     plural = True if pluralForm is not singularForm else False
     return plural, singularForm

nounls = ['geese', 'mice', 'bars', 'foos', 'foo', 
            'families', 'family', 'dog', 'dogs']

for pluralForm in nounls:
    isp, singularForm = isplural(pluralForm)
    print pluralForm, singularForm, isp
```

which outputs

```
geese goose True
mice mouse True
bars bar True
foos foo True
foo foo False
families family True
family family False
dog dog False
dogs dog True
```

the only difference in output between 2er0's solution and this is

```
foos foo True
```

since his solution outputs `False`, as he pointed out since `foos` is not in wordnet (and not an English word at all).