# How to delete a row if value include plural form of the words?

Tags: pandas, parsing

Delete a row if value include the plural form of the words and only if exists the single form of word too, for example DataFrame contains 'test' and 'tests' or 'company' and 'companies', that is will be delete 'tests' and 'companies'. And next I want to apply another rules word formation [rules](https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/plural-forms-english-nouns/)

Original Dataframe

```
d0 = [{'word':'test', 'count':22}, {'word':'tests', 'count':11},{'word':'company', 'count':2},{'word':'companies', 'count':5}]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(d0)
```

Desirable DataFrame

```
d1 = [{'word':'test', 'count':22}, {'word':'company', 'count':11}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546883/singular-and-plural-words-matching-with-pandas this will be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
import nltk 
nltk.download('wordnet')

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

d0 = [{'word':'test', 'count':22}, {'word':'tests', 'count':11},{'word':'company', 'count':2},{'word':'companies', 'count':5},
     {'word':'debris', 'count':5}]

def not_plural(word):
    lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, 'n')
    not_plural = False if word is not lemma else True
    return not_plural

df1 = df0[df0.word.apply(not_plural)]
df1

      word  count
0     test     22
2  company      2
4   debris      5
```

credit: [How to test whether a word is in singular form or not in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911589/how-to-test-whether-a-word-is-in-singular-form-or-not-in-python)

Comment: This test will fail for words like 'debris'. I'm guessing to find all plural words you'll need to do some kind of stemming, or maintain your own mapping.

Comment: I have an error ((. It's too difficult for me:
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')

Comment: it means you need to download 'wordnet'. pls do: ` import nltk nltk.download('wordnet')`. I updated the answer; in case someone else would need.